# Cannot bring up MacVim 7.4 on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, macports, macvim

I just installed MacVim 7.4 on Mac OS X Lion through macports, but I cannot bring it up? Typing mvim in the terminal invokes the application but doesn't bring up any window (and doesn't print anything to the terminal). mvim -v works though and brings up vim in the terminal.

Any idea why the GUI version doesn't work?

P.S. I also tried File -> New Window. It doesn't work either.

Thanks!

Comment: I use MacPorts version 2.2.1 in case it helps.

Comment: I reinstalled it and it just worked. spooky!